# Two dependent NodeJS database actions in one function. What if the second fails?

Tags: node.js, express

I have two database mutations in one function. I can imagine a scenario when the first mutation succeeds and the second one fails. The first one changed something and the second one failed. Can I somehow undo the first mutation?

```
export const postReset = async (req, res, next) => {
  const cardId = req.body.cardId;
  const userId = req.user?.id;

  if (!cardId || !userId) {
    return res.status(404).json({
      success: false,
    });
  }
  try {
    // First mutation
    const cardRemoved = await UsersModel.updateOne(
      { _id: userId },
      { $pull: { cards: { cardId: cardId } } },
      { safe: true, multi: true }
    );

    if (!cardRemoved) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        success: false,
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(404).json({
      success: false,
    });
  }
  try {
    // Second mutation
    const cardRemovedFromCardsColelction = await CardsModel.findOneAndDelete({
      cardId: cardId,
      cardOwner: userId,
    });
    if (!cardRemovedFromCardsColelction) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        success: false,
      });
    }
    return res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(404).json({
      success: false,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: You're looking for a "transaction".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your queries must be part of a single transaction. Then, if for any reason execution in the transaction fails - intended changes will not be persisted in the database.

The basic example:

```
const doc = new Person({ name: 'Will Riker' });

await db.transaction(async function setRank(session) {
  doc.name = 'Captain';
  await doc.save({ session });

  // Throw an error to abort the transaction
  throw new Error('Oops!');
}).catch(() => {}); // doc wasn't saved in the end
```

More details and explanations regarding transactions utilisation with Mongoose can be found [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html).